# Pluralize String from command line in C

Tags: c

This file compiles and runs but with error. This is a homework assignment that I have mostly completed but it doesn't output properly. I'm not asking for a reworked design of my program rather a helpful hint on what I am doing wrong. The error is in the output every other word gets messed up and I cant figure out why. Thank you for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

void plural(char word[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc >= 2)
    {
    int i;
        for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
        {
            printf("noun: %s\n",argv[i]);
            plural(argv[i]);
            printf("plural: %s\n\n", argv[i]);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: You must pass the nouns to be pluralized as program arguements\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void plural(char word[])
{
    /* declarations */  
    int length;

    /* find length of word */
    length = strlen(word);

    /* check first rule:  if word ends in "y" then change to "ies" */
    if (word[length - 1] == 'y') {
        word[length - 1] = 'i';
        word[length] = 'e';
        word[length + 1] = 's';
        word[length + 2] = '\0';   /* put '\0' at end of string */
    }

    /* check second rule:  if word ends in "s" "ch" or "sh" add "es" */
    else if (word[length - 1] == 's' ||
        (word[length - 2] == 'c' && word[length - 1] == 'h') ||
        (word[length - 2] == 's' && word[length - 1] == 'h'))
    {
        /* concatenate "es" to word */
        strcat(word, "es");
    }

    /* otherwise, just add "s" to the end of word */
    else 
    {
        strcat(word, "s");
    } 

}
```

Comment: You cannot write outside the `lenght` of string. `word[length + 1]` and `word[length + 2]` are wrong. You should use a new larger string to store the plural.

Comment: Indeed. While C standard says that the argv strings are modifiable, they still have a fixed length of memory allocated - `strlen(argv[n]) + 1` bytes, so you're not to write past this. Same applies to `strcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write outside the `length` of string. `word[length + 1]` and `word[length + 2]` are wrong. You should use a new larger string to store the plural.

You could simply copy argv into a new larger string:

```
#define SIZE 128

void plural(char word[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char plural_string[SIZE] = {0};

    if(argc >= 2)
    {
        int i;

        for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
        {
            printf("noun: %s\n",argv[i]);
            strncpy(plural_string, argv[i], SIZE);
            plural(plural_string);
            printf("plural: %s\n\n", plural_string);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: You must pass the nouns to be pluralized as program arguements\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take also note that plural function has to take care of minimum allowed length of string.`word[length - 2]` could index your array out of bounds.

Comment: I'm wondering: Will `word[length - 1]` be out of bounds? I mean, `length` will always be >= 1 since we are dealing with `argv[i]`, right?

Comment: @LPs thank you for the help and keeping most of my code the same. If i put a if statement outside the if else statements in plural() that checked if(length>2) should that take care of the out of bounds? and was there a reasoning on choosing 128 as the define for SIZE?

Comment: @TAG `128` is big enough to store the biggest word. `35` should be fine also to store Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious. ;). `if (length>2)` should be fine to check the passed string.

Comment: @LPs thank you again for the help tonight, the code now works properly thanks to your input!

Answer (score 3):

Each `argv[i]` has `strlen(argv[i]) + 1` memory allocated to it. You write more characters, which goes into invalid memory locations invoking Undefined Behavior.

The fix is to create a pointer from the function, and `malloc` memory as required, returning the pointer and `free`ing it from `main`.

See this code *(untested)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20
/* Note: SIZE is unused */

char* plural(char word[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc >= 2)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("noun: %s\n", argv[i]);
            char* str = plural(argv[i]);
            printf("plural: %s\n\n", str);

            free(str);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: You must pass the nouns to be pluralized as program arguements\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

char* plural(char word[])
{
    /* declarations */  
    int length;
    char* str;

    /* find length of word */
    length = strlen(word);

    /* check first rule:  if word ends in "y" then change to "ies" */
    if (word[length - 1] == 'y') {
        str = malloc(length + 3);
        strcpy(str, word);
        strcpy(str + length - 1, "ies");
    }

    /* check second rule:  if word ends in "s" "ch" or "sh" add "es" */
    else if (word[length - 1] == 's' ||
        (length > 1 && word[length - 2] == 'c' && word[length - 1] == 'h') ||
        (length > 1 && word[length - 2] == 's' && word[length - 1] == 'h'))
    {
        str = malloc(length + 3);
        strcpy(str, word);
        /* concatenate "es" to word */
        strcat(str, "es");
    }

    /* otherwise, just add "s" to the end of word */
    else 
    {
        str = malloc(length + 2);
        strcpy(str, word);
        strcat(str, "s");
    } 

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Good to say that program will crash for `word[length - 2]` if `length` < 2

Comment: @Cool Guy, you used  `char* plural(char word[])` declaration but forgot to return `char *`

Comment: @AbdulGafoor Whoops. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @AlterMann Good catch. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: @Cool Guy, missing semicolon in last else statement after strcpy. other than that the code works well except for words that have a y the y never gets removed and it just adds ies. i.e. fly turns into flyies

Comment: @Cool Guy, Thank you for your help tonight with my code

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `argv` parameter list as if they were modifiable strings. Most importantly, you don't know how much memory that was allocated for them beyond their length, so you can't use things like `strcat`, it will create array out of bounds bugs.

Instead, make a hard copy of each such parameter before modifying it.

Comment: Are you saying to essentially make a new array of the values that were entered and work with that array?

Comment: @TAG If you need to modify the values, then yes. An array of pointers where each pointer points to a string is probably the best choice for that, since your program can't know the string lengths at compile-time.